# DATE LOOP in Matlab

Tags: date, loops, for-loop

I'm using an input file that contains dates in the following format:

```
1st column: year
2nd column: month
3rd column: day
```

So if I want to do something for example with the jul 15th data of 2008 I do the following:

```
[n,m] = size(INPUT);
for i=1:n
    if INPUT(i,1)==2008 && INPUT(i,2)==7 && INPUT(i,3)==15
        {...do something...}
    end
end
```

This works for a given date, but how can I make this with another FOR loop (or loops) for example from Jul 15th to Oct 20th?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the 3 input values to a date type first and do the comparison afterwards on the two dates (also as a date type) of the daterange.

Comment: have you figured it out or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

try to use Matlab built-in functions like find().

in your case you can use the one-liner

```
INPUT(find( (INPUT(:,1)<18) & (INPUT(:,1)>15) & (INPUT(:,2)==7) & (INPUT(:,3)==2008) ),:)
```

hope that helped,

Edit:

sorry - had some problems with the comment-function - 
you can use a second temp variable for further checks - like this:

```
out = INPUT(find( (INPUT(:,3)==2008)),:) %find right year
out = out(find( (out(:,2)>=7) & (out(:,2)<=10)),:) %find right months
our = out(find( ~ ( (out(:,1)<=15) & (out(:,2)==7))) ,:) %filter day
our = out(find( ~ ( (out(:,1)>=20) & (out(:,2)==10))) ,:) %filter day
```

jens.

Comment: and if I need the data from Jul 15th to Oct 20th?

Comment: see my edit ;-) - you can play around with logical expressions inside the find-function

Comment: another option is - as t7bdh3hdhb proposed - to use Matlab built-in date-functionality - see http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2011/11/28/using-dates-in-matlab/